# Potential Theory vs Harmonic Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

In layman's terms, what is the difference between Harmonic analysis and Potential Theory? Could you please give a quick synopsis of what each is trying to study?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_theory

Comment: So.... I'm trying to confirm then (I don't have the math no-how): Potential theory is a superset of Harmonic analysis yes?

Comment: You clearly know something about set theory. Harmonic Functions are not the same as Harmonic Analysis if that's what you mean.

Comment: @BertolucciBuilds Well shouldn't it be the other way around? Potential theory is a subclass of Harmonic Analysis

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, they are different topics. "Harmonic analysis" is kind of a misleading term, as it doesn't deal with harmonic functions (or subharmonic, pluriharmonic, plurisubharmonic, quasi-plurisubharmonic...). Perhaps what you wanted from this question was confirmation of that fact.

The field that is concerned with harmonic and subharmonic functions is called potential theory.

I am sure that there are connections between the two, but to my knowledge not fundamental ones, and neither could be called a superset of the other.